# How do I trick Nautilus to use "sudo mount" instead of just "mount"?

Tags: linux, mount, sudo, cifs

Thanks to new "security fixes" in mount or mount.cifs (I'm not sure which) it's no longer possible for normal users to mount anything, even if they are explicitly allowed using the `user`, `users` or `owner` flags. For that reason, I've changed my sudo config to allow my user to run the specific mount commands for my network shares without a password. Then I made a script under `$HOME/bin` called `mount` which contains:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mount "$*"
```

So now I can basically use mount like I used to, without having to type a password. The problem is that I can't mount my network shares using Nautilus, which is far more convenient. I'm using the flag `noauto` in fstab because otherwise the mount will take place before I've established a wireless network connection and immediately fail.

The shares show up in Nautilus as greyed out folders, and when I click the folder Nautilus attempts to mount the share using a command like this (I think):

```
/usr/bin/mount "/media/My Network Share"
```

Which fails, because it doesn't use `sudo`. I have tried to do:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" nautilus
```

But the error still occurs, presumably because Nautilus uses the absolute path to `mount`.

So my question is: is there a way I can trick Nautilus into using `sudo /usr/bin/mount`, or even just `mount` without the absolute path?

---

My last resort is basically to *move* the `mount` binary somewhere else and replacing it with a bash script. The bash script would check which user is executing it, and if it's my user, it will append `sudo` in front of the command. Otherwise it would just call the actual mount executable normally. I hope to avoid going to such drastic measures though, as I could easily destroy my system beyond my ability to repair.

Answer (score 1):

You can make linux binaries executable with root permissions by setting the setuid attribute on the executable that you need to call. You may also want to create a group which only has access to mount things (unless it's a single install, then you can just use your user group). So something like the following in a root shell:

```
# groupadd mounters
# usermod -a -G mounters yourusername
# chgrp mounters /bin/mount
# chmod g+s /bin/mount
```

So that creates a group called "mounters", adds your user to that group, then changes the group on /bin/mount to "mounters", then sets the setuid attribute just for that group in /bin/mount. If you then execute that binary, you should effectively be executing it as root.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid for more information.

Comment: +1 Awesome answer, and I think it actually solves my problem, but unfortunately it doesn't answer the question so I can't accept it in good conscience.